# Should I call Parse.initialize() on top of every jQuery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, parse-platform

I am using Parse and jQuery to build a full HTML5 + JS application, and I am a little confused about where the Parse Object is available whithin my code. I am initializing parse in my first line of jQuery using parse initalize, within a `$(document).ready(...)` construct.

However, the Parse object is not available in other `$(document).ready(...)` constructs and plugins. I thought that was because the object was garbage collected at the end of each construct, but declaring it outside of the construct doesn't solve the problem.

So far I am calling Parse Initialize on top of all my different files, but I believe this is a bad practise, and there must be a way to initialize Parse once, et get access to the Parse object from all other my app.

Any indication on how to make this possible is most welmcomed

Comment: Don't call `Parse.initialize()` within a document.ready handler, otherwise its scope will be local to that handler. You need to structure your logic to call it once within the context of a page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `Parse.initialize()` outside any other function (including any `$(document).ready(function() {...});`, so it is in the global scope and accessible from anywhere.

Comment: `Parse` is already in global scope. Doesn't matter if you initialize it inside a load handler so long as you don't try making API calls until it is initialized

Answer (score 0):

My bad. Many thanks for your answers. 
I was actually editing the wrong file...

Calling `Parse.initialize()` from within `$(document).ready(...)` handler actually does make the Parse object available to other jQuery plugins.